# Spring Boot url endpoint

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot project whose endpoint is localhost:8080/ as opposed to localhost:8080/projectname/

My current mvcinitializer is as follows :

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringRootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ThymeleafConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override 
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] {new EmailVerificationFilter()};
    }
}
```

is there anyway for me to achieve the behavior described above?

Comment: This *is* how Spring Boot application behaves out of the box with no special configuration (try generating a vanilla webapp at http://start.spring.io). If you're deploying a .war to a standalone Tomcat then context is cojfigured outside the app (search for "root context")

Comment: thanks! that solved my problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the setting `server.contextPath` in your application.properties file:

`server.contextPath=/projectname`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. However, how do actually load that properties into the servlet? does spring find it automatically in the classpath?

Comment: so I've done some reading and I've learned that the application.properties file should be resolved by itself within the classpath. I in fact have already been using an application.properties file in a resources source folder and have loaded the properties via an Autowired Environment variable. Despite this, even thought I configure server.context-path in that file I don't get the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: In spring boot application.properties is discovered automatically - but you would have to post your configuration classes to find out where your problem comes from.

Comment: is it the servlet or the root config that would interact with the application.properties? Is there anyway easy way to test to see if it's loading the properties file?

Comment: During startup of my spring boot application I can see the following log output that indicates that my configuration is picked up: `2015-12-16 09:01:40.992 DEBUG 4555 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'classpath:/config/application.yml'`